# Django - Sum if another column is distinct

Tags: sql, django, django-orm

I have a two tables in djagno

```
class Item(models.model):
    name = models.TextField()
    type = models.ForeignKey(ItemType)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

and

```
class ProductionRecord(models.model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    done = models.IntegerField()
```

What i am wanting to do is group the items by its type, sum the total quantity of items needed, and then sum the total quantity of items produced.

I was fairly close but the issue i ran into was that when doing `.annotate(Sum("quantity"))` if an item has multiple production records, it will sum the quantity again, per record.

Below is an example of my current data set after joining the tables and before grouping.

`+--------+--------+--------------+----------------------+
| ItemId | TypeId | ItemQuantity | ProductionRecordDone |
+--------+--------+--------------+----------------------+
|   1257 |      7 |            4 |                    1 |
|   1257 |      7 |            4 |                    4 |
|   1259 |      7 |            4 |                    4 |
|   1261 |      7 |            4 |                    0 |
|   1263 |      7 |            4 |                    4 |
|   1265 |      7 |            4 |                    0 |
+--------+--------+--------------+----------------------+`

When doing a normal sum on the quantity column, it returns 24 because it is summing for item id=1257 twice.

But what i would like to return after grouping is:

`+--------+--------------+------+
| TypeId | ItemQuantity | Done |
+--------+--------------+------+
|      7 |           20 |   13 |
+--------+--------------+------+`

Here is my current python code for reference

```
Item.objects.values("type__name", "type__id") \
            .annotate(total_done=Coalesce(Sum("productionrecord__done"), 0),
                      total_quantity=Coalesce(Sum("quantity",), 1))
```

Is there any code that can be used to only sum the quantity in rows where the ItemId is distinct?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
queryset = Item.objects.values("type__name", "type__id") \
    .filter(productionrecord__done=True) \
    .annotate(total_done=Count("*"),
              total_quantity=Sum("quantity"))
```

Pls, show the `queryset.query` if it doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done in one query, since the sum of the quantities will compound when making the outer join with the production records.
However, you can do two queries, and combine the dicts:

```py
    data = {}
    quantities = (
        Item.objects.order_by("type_id")
        .values("type_id")
        .annotate(to_produce=Coalesce(Sum("quantity"), 1),)
    )
    for item in quantities:
        type_id = item.pop("type_id")
        data[type_id] = item
    done = (
        Item.objects.order_by("type_id")
        .values("type_id")
        .annotate(done=Coalesce(Sum("productionrecord__done"), 1),)
    )
    for item in done:
        item_type_id = item.pop("type_id")
        data[type_id].update(item)

    for type_id, numbers in data.items():
        print(type_id, numbers.get("to_produce"), numbers.get("done"))
```